# SSL cipher mismatch error -- IBM http server

Tags: httpd.conf, vhosts

We have a secure page that throws a cipher mismatch error while accessing it on Google Chrome but not via Internet explorer or Mozilla Firefox. After some troubleshooting and searching we've included the following line under the conf file for the specific webpage under vhosts.d, say xy.conf

> SSLCipherSpec TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

This seems to have resolved the issue. But only after we edited the last line of httpd.conf from

> Include httpconf/vhosts.d/*.conf

to

> Include httpconf/vhosts.d/xy.conf

If we revert changes to include all conf files as *.conf, we get the cipher mismatch error. So to zero down on the faulty conf file we've edited the line to include all the conf files as such :

> Include httpconf/vhosts.d/xy*.conf
>
> Include httpconf/vhosts.d/ab*.conf
>
> Include httpconf/vhosts.d/cd*.conf

But not able to get the faulty conf file if we do so.

My question is what is the problem when using *.conf? 
There are no duplicate files (AIX) or any sub directories created under the vhosts.d folder.

Comment: Try to list them without any asterix: `find httpconf/vhosts.d/ -name '*.conf' -exec echo 'include {}' \; | sort >>config` If it shows the problem try to find the problem via 'binary search'

Comment: *.conf will include every file which ends in .conf in that directory and one may be overwritting the behaviour you define in another. If you just have one file there you want to use, by all means specify it literally and avoid wildcards for issues and confusions like this actual question.